# Get X-Coordinate of Elliptical Curve using Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I tried to calculate Tr(x) operation for x coordinate of the elliptical curve F2m (m = 163). For that, I used "Bouncy Castle" with corresponding types. Trace for my elliptical curve is equal to either 0 or 1 and my code is the following:

```
public int CalculateTrace_Test(byte[] array)
{
    int m = 163;            
    BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2", 10);
    BigInteger x = new BigInteger(array);
    BigInteger xi = x;
    BigInteger temp = x;
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
    {
        var next = xi.ModPow(two.Pow(i), fx);
        temp = temp.Xor(next);
    }

    return temp.IntValue;
}
```

Here fx is an integer formed from the irreducible polynomial `f(x) = x^163+x^7+x^6+x^3 + 1`.

So my problem that it doesn't work and as result, I have everything but not 1 or 0. Could anyone please tell me what is wrong in my implementation of the trace?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are properly doing field arithmetic in GF(2<sup>m</sup>). The classes that support correct field arithmetic are in the package [`org.bouncycastle.math.ec`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/package-frame.html). Take a look at [`ECFieldElement.F2m`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/ECFieldElement.F2m.html) and [`ECCurve.F2m`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/ECCurve.F2m.html). Also, for your specific case which corresponds to the SECT163 reduction polynomial, the class [`SecT163FieldElement`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/custom/sec/SecT163FieldElement.html) may be particularly useful.

Here some code copied directly from the class [`org.bouncycastle.math.ec.tools.TraceOptimizer`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/tools/TraceOptimizer.html). The code assumes the the finite field is of characteristic 2.

```
private static int calculateTrace(ECFieldElement fe) {
    int m = fe.getFieldSize();
    ECFieldElement tr = fe;
    for (int i = 1; i < m; ++i) {
        fe = fe.square();
        tr = tr.add(fe);
    }
    BigInteger b = tr.toBigInteger();
    if (b.bitLength() > 1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    return b.intValue();
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is "characteristic 2" ? F2m ?

Comment: No wikipedia for you? Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Definitions,_first_examples,_and_basic_properties).

Comment: Thank You, i adapted your code because in C# version "BouncyCastle"  there are no such classes and now it does work. About "characteristic 2", in your code ECFieldElement  is used, not F2mFieldElement in case of the binary fields

Comment: There is no C# in the question nor answer, so I'm not sure what that comment is about.

Comment: @RotvikKnuzich: If you were interested in C# then why not mention that in your question?